# Range.Find to match column

Tags: excel, match, vba

I am trying to match col C and col B from 2 different worksheets (wsMaster & wsSample) and retrieve col F from wsSample to put it inside col D in wsMaster. My code below run but there is no results. Anything wrong with my codes?

```
j = 2    
Do While wsMaster.Cells(j, 3).Value <> ""
    Set rngcell = wsSample.Range("B:B").Find(What:=wsMaster.Cells(j, 3), After:=wsSample.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not rngcell Is Nothing Then wsMaster.Cells(j, 4) = rngcell.Offset(0, 4)
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

Local windows show that my rngcell = Nothing but I'm not very sure why.
Thank you!!

Comment: If you don't get an error message with this code, you probably have a `On Error Resume Next` anywhere. If so remove that and change it into a proper error handling. Otherwise you are blind for any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's surprising your code runs, it should give you

> run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Either change to:

```
Set rngcell = wsSample.Range("B:B").Find(What:=wsMaster.Cells(j, 3), After:=wsSample.Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

or just remove the `After` entirely:

```
Set rngcell = wsSample.Range("B:B").Find(What:=wsMaster.Cells(j, 3), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

**Note**: You could also change `Range("B:B")` to `Columns(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching in `Range("B:B")` AFTER `Range("A2")`. Thus, it does not find anything. Change the `After` range to correspond to the searched range.

Check this code, which has the searched value in the searched range, but it gives error 13, because the `After` is in another range:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    'On Error Resume Next        
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Range("B1") = "test"
    Set rngCell = Range("B:B").Find("test", Range("A1"))
    If rngCell Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "Not Found!"    
End Sub
```

If you uncomment the `On Error Resume Next` (which you are probably using), it will not find the value.

Comment: I see you beat me to it, well I'm a s l o w typer :)

Comment: @ShaiRado - in general you type pretty fast.

Comment: @Vityata, thank you! tried it out and at least now I understand what is wrong with it.